# Java FXML calling methods on button clicks

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am creating a basic game launcher in JavaFX with SceneBuilder. Since SceneBuilder works in FXML, my launcher layout is in FXML. I have a method in my main class that I want to call on a button click. I read that you could use

```
#methodName
```

In the button's

```
onAction
```

property, but this does not work.

My main Java class:

```
@FXML
private void launchGame(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Launching...");
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("launcher.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setTitle("First Week Login");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

My FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102">
<children>
  <BorderPane prefHeight="493.0" prefWidth="664.0" styleClass="background" 
stylesheets="@launcher.css">
     <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <children>
              <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" 
text="Launch Game" onAction="#launchGame" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
     </bottom>
     <top>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <children>
              <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" 
styleClass="title" text="First Week" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
     </top>
     <center>
        <WebView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
     </center>
  </BorderPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit the FXML file directly. SceneBuilder allows you to specify a controller, component ids and actions. Did you specify the action via SceneBuilder?

Comment: No I didn't, I wrote into it in Eclipse

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Should definitely use SceneBuilder for that. You should almost never have to edit the FXML file directly when you're using SceneBuilder.

Comment: SceneBuilder can also generate the skeleton code for the controller, once you have added `fx:id`s and event handlers, and specified a controller class. Go to "View" on the menu and choose "Show skeleton controller code". Then you can copy and paste the controller code into your IDE (the controller must be edited in an IDE, not in SceneBuilder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a separate Controller class and specify it in top `AnchorPane` tag with `fx:controller="packageName.Classname"`

Like this:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102"
 fx:controller="com.packageName.Controller">
```

The called method should be inside the specified Controller class.

`com.packageName` is just an example, you should use the name of the package where you put the Controller class or no package name if it's not in any package.